# Excel formula count after certain observation in c horological order

Tags: excel, count, formula

I am having tough time building a logic around this problem for a while , Hope some one can help.

I have 3 column of data. Lets call them Customer ID , Call ID , Agent ID
Customer ID  and Agent ID can have repetition however Call ID is unique .

Now i have a table with these columns- they are stacked in chronological order based on date or time. Also one customer can call multiple time to multiple agent generating unique caller ID every time.

Here i want to count number of time one customer has called after certain agent ID has received the call. So count or freq function will have to have a rule embedded in chronological function or "Count **after** certain rule has been met"

Below is the table

```
CusID CalID Agent
1     123  a
1     22   b                    
1     112  a
1     222  a
1     54   a
1    334   a
2    221   a
2    312   b
2    334   b
2    129   b
2    986   a
4     98   b
```

In above table i want to calculate number of observation for customer id '1'after he has called to agent 'b' so the answer will be 4. I have used couple of unique count based no multiple crietria using combination of sumif 1/countif however major problem is counting after certain observation.

can any one help

Comment: after the first time or the last time?  for ex cusID 2 agent b is three time, do we count the last 2 or only the a?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this formula that will change the range to count to match where b is found the first time.

```
=COUNTIF(INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($C$2:$C$13)/(($C$2:$C$13=E3)*($A$2:$A$13=E2)),1)+1):$A$13,E2)
```

[image]

Comment: it would be me!